# Regex for date of birth

Tags: regex

I am trying to implement a regex for date of birth in the format of MM/DD/YYYY.
I could not figure out how to force users in typing 01-12 for MM, 01-31 for day, and any four
digits for year.
I simply have a regex for MM/DD/YYYY which is @"^\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{4}$".
Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: There are good date parsing libraries in every language I know of.  Why not use one?

Comment: @NickC +1. There's even one built into bash!

Comment: If you say us the language you use, I am sure somebody will give you 'the correct'/'a more precise' answer.

Answer (score 3):

The regex gets pretty ugly, so it's probably best to use a legitimate date parser.

That said, this should work, and return the MM, DD, and YYYY match groups.

`((?:0[1-9])|(?:1[0-2]))\/((?:0[0-9])|(?:[1-2][0-9])|(?:3[0-1]))\/(\d{4})`

Recommend http://www.rubular.com or similar for testing/developing a regex.

Comment: What do you mean by "rubular or similar"?

Comment: A website that lets you test regular expressions in real time so that you can see the results and adjust as necessary to get the intended output.  rubular is simply one example of such a site.

Comment: I've added more precise validation of the year:  
`^((?:0[0-9])|(?:[1-2][0-9])|(?:3[0-1]))/((?:0[1-9])|(?:1[0-2]))/((?:19|20)\d{2})$`

Answer (score 0):

I recently used this regex in one of my projects

```
^(0?[1-9]|1[0-2])/([0-2]?[1-9]|[1-3][01])/\d{4}$
```

This obviously works for all dates in `dd/MM/yyyy` format but you may not specify '0' when it's not necessary. So you can write '01/01/2000' as well as '1/1/2000'.